# empty response from axios POST in react app, rails server shows 201 status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jwt

I have a react front end that connects to a rails API, using Knock and JWT to authenticate users. I send email and password in a post request and then keep the token (from the response data) in localStorage to pass it around for other functions.

On submitting the log in form the rails console shows status 201, but the response in from my post request is empty (not an error)

Here is the post request:

```
login () {
   const $ = window.$;
   const email = $("#email").val()
   const password = $("#password").val()
   const request = {"auth": {"email": email, "password": password}}
   console.log(request)

   axios.post('api/v1/user_token', request)
     .then(response => {
     console.log(response)
     localStorage.setItem("jwt", response.jwt)
   })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

in my rails console I see

```
Completed 201 Created in 112ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

And no errors in the Javascript console.

I tried removing Knock, and rewriting a basic Authentication from scratch, and the same problem, even if the server generates a token, I can't get it back in the response to the post request. If I hard code a token into a get request, it works and I get data back.

Here is the user_tokens controller created from Knock install

```
module Api::V1
  class UserTokenController < Knock::AuthTokenController
  end
end
```

And my (very minimal) user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  has_many :events 
end

(byebug) request.content_type
"application/json"
(byebug) request.format
#<Mime::Type:0x00007fef56c28650 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], 
@symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=-2331784109630414172>
(byebug) request.accept
"application/json, text/plain, */*"

.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb
134:         when '', nil
135:         else
136:           env[RACK_ERRORS].puts "Unknown x-sendfile variation: '# 
.{type}'.\n"
137:         end
138:       end
139:       [status, headers, body]
140:     end
141: 
142:     private
143:     def variation(env)
(byebug) status
201
(byebug) headers
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", 
"X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Content- 
Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", 
"ETag"=>"W/\"6d43c14099bd994119752b6ad84913c1\"", "Cache- 
Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "X-Request- 
Id"=>"e1004d69-e7ef-4145-8b62-bb86e2325ea8", "X- 
Runtime"=>"1585.123732"}
```

I'm new to react, so maybe I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: Please provide your controller source and full log output... This is like looking into crystal ball :)

Comment: Try to send Accept and Content-Type headers and please provide full rails log of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using the proxy set up in package.json for the React front end:

```
"proxy": {
  "/api/v1": {
  "target": "http://localhost:3001"
   }
},
```

I created a custom axios component:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001/'
})

export default instance
```

and disabled Chrome security tools and was able to retrieve a valid token. This solves the problem I was having in development environment, and allows me to update localStorage with the token after each successful request.